# RxJS: Retry a part of the chain

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

```
return this.showPasswordDialog()
    .flatMap(password => doSomethingAndReturnPromise(..))
    .subscribe(console.log);
```

I have a password dialog which returns me an `Observable` where I can subscribe and get the password from.

That password gets passed to a function `doSomethingAndReturnPromise` which 1) can succeed 2) or fail but always returns a promise.

In case of failure I want to show the password dialog and pass it to the promise function again... but maximum 3 times.

How can I use the RxJS `retry(3)` operator in such a way that the dialog and the `doSomethingAndReturnPromise` chain is retried as a whole?

Comment: Does adding `retry` not work?

Answer (score 1):

You just put the `retry(3)` after `flatMap`:

```
return this.showPasswordDialog()
  .flatMap(password => doSomethingAndReturnPromise(..))
  .retry(3)
  .subscribe(console.log);
```